# Error : has a @IonicPage decorator, but it does not have a corresponding "NgModule"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

> C:\wamp\www\Ionic4\ionic3-angular4\src\pages\home\home.ts has a
>   @IonicPage decorator, but it does not have a corresponding "NgModule"
>   at C:\wamp\www\Ionic4\ionic3-angular4\src\pages\home\home.module.ts

*home.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({
     name: 'home'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

*home.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage} from './home';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomePage],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage)],
  entryComponents: [HomePage]

})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `home.module.ts` should be like below.You have missed some properties on `@NgModule`.You don't need to use `entryComponents: [HomePage]` inside your `module.ts` file.So try as shown below.

**Note:** + The key issue is the missing `exports` array.

*home.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage} from './home';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```