# Cannot create routes on Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I want to see the actual route on the url but I can't figure out what I need to change exactly.

I'm following the docs here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/

but I get this error:

> ...home.ts has a @IonicPage decorator, but it does not have 
>               a corresponding "NgModule" at...
>   I have this on the top of my page:

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'sums-home',
  segment: 'sums-home'
})
```

I created the home.module.ts file with this code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

import { SumsHomePage} from './home';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SumsHomePage} from './home';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SumsHomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SumsHomePage),
  ],
  exports: [
    SumsHomePage
  ]
})
export class SumsHomePageModule { }
```

and I go to this page doing:

```
this.navCtrl.push('sums-home');
```

but I think it should have something else.

Does anyone archived this?

Answer (score 5):

i was having the same problem on my Desktop Ionic project, and found this solution using **DeepLinks** :

`imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
      links: [
        { component: HomePage, name: 'Home', segment: 'home' },
        { component: LoginPage, name: 'Login', segment: 'login' },
        { component: UsersPage, name: 'Users', segment: 'users' },
        { component: TrophiesPage, name: 'Trophies', segment: 'trophies' }
      ]
    }),
    HttpModule,
    LoginPageModule,
    UsersPageModule,
    TrophiesPageModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [Http]
      }
    }),
  ]`

Just notice **links** property used in **IonicModule.forRoot** import.
Now when i use:

`this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);`

I get correctly redirected to url "http://localhost:8100/#/home".
Hope it'll help. Peace

Comment: I added the link with my page on app.modules.ts and I changed this.navCtrl.push('sums-home'); for this.navCtrl.setRoot(SumsHomePage); (I also importing SumsHomePage on that Page and on app.modules.ts as well) but doesn't work. Also I lose the arrow for going back

Comment: You must use @IonicPage() on your ComponentPage; and in order to make this work you have to declare a NgModule (SumsHomePageModule) declaring and exporting the Component. Then in your app.module.ts, don't declare SumsHomePage, you just have to import SumsHomePageModule which will bring the ComponentPage.

Answer (score 1):

If `SumsHomePage` has an `@IonicPage()` decorator your corresponding module shoud look like this:

```
@NgModule({  
  declarations: [  
    SumsHomePage  
  ],  
  imports: [  
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SumsHomePage)  
  ]  
})
```

I don't think you need it in the entryComponents array but adding it will do no harm.

Comment: I'm starting to feel a bit confusing with all of these configurations. Would you have a repo/example with this? I've created this one: https://github.com/erperejildo/url-not-changing

Comment: And I also tried that code on home.module.ts but didn't work, but as I said above I'm not quite sure if I need to modify something else

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/) blog post, there are example repos linked at the end of the article. You maybe also want to read [part 1](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/).

Comment: Perfect, I followed those repo and I found the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I found 2 issues: 1- when I go back the url still there.  2- When I refresh the page being on that url and I press back I move again to the same page, not the previous one

Comment: Nice, I'm glad you could solve your issue! Yes ionics navigation is quite broken in some parts currently (see the many issues on github). According to the team these issues will be fixed after (or with) the version 4 release of ionic.

Comment: It's quite disappointing starting with a new framework and find that the easiest possible thing, like the routing, is not working properly or you have to spend 1 weeks figuring out how can you move from route1 to route2. Ionic is now on its 3 (main) version. How is this possible?

Comment: Well you're kind of mixing up a few things here. Changing pages/routes and also lazy loading works perfectly fine. Its just not the easiest thing to wrap your head aroung things like modularization in angular4, lazy loading pages, pushing a page onto the nav stack, webpack and how it is all connected. This is going to take some time and experience with all the technologies that are combined here. The issues you are seeing are browser related which is still not fully optimized (like urls, back-navigation), first of all ionic was created for apps and now its being optimized for browsers/pwa too.

Comment: You are not the first one to point me to lazy loading. Tbh I haven't talked about it. I don't if lazy loading is related in some way with paths. But yes, maybe I'm mixin Angular4 and Ionic3. I just came from AngularJS (but with TS) so that could be the mess

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your `module` as shown below. But if you use latest `CLI` this is done by it automatically for you.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SumsHomePage } from './SumsHome';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SumsHomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SumsHomePage),
  ],
})
export class SumsHomePageModule { }
```

Comment: I tried 2 approaches: 
1) add that on my app.modules.ts (didn't work)   
2) create a home.module.ts on my component folder with that code but I get this issue "Cannot find name 'IonicPageModule'"

Comment: You just need to import this `import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: Yes, it's imported. Dunno then... I'll give it a workaround

Comment: Can you show the `code` of that `module`? Update it on your question above.

Comment: Ok, I had a non removed line on app.module.ts (my bad).
Now I'm getting this: "Error: Type SumsHomePage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and HomePageModule! Please consider moving SumsHomePage to a higher module that imports AppModule and HomePageModule".
Question: why are you using here an export? Is that necessary? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518383/error-has-a-ionicpage-decorator-but-it-does-not-have-a-corresponding-ngmodu

Comment: If you're using lazy loading then you don't need to put anything on `app.module.ts`. remove all related stuff from that (i.e. `SumsHomePage`).See this too : http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/

Comment: I'm not using any loading component at all on my app. It's basically a main page with a modal (which is working) and this other redirection on the url. It's quite basic so far, nothing else

Comment: Then why do you need a separate `module` for the page? If you're not using lazy loading then you don't need it.

Comment: What I'm trying to archive is just be redirected to a new page having the path/route on the url. On Ionic documentation says that I'd need to use IonicPage but is here where I get stuck

Comment: Should I create a component instead maybe?

Comment: If you need to use deep linking then you need to create a separate module for that. But it seems you have a serious issue with the names of the pages. If you have `SumsHomePage` then your module's name also like this `SumsHomePageModule`. Just see my update above. Remove reference for that page from the `app.module`.

Comment: Removing references on app.modules.ts and changing the module name I get this working but the url doesn't change

Comment: You need to set it like this `@IonicPage({
  name: 'my-page',
  segment: 'some-path'
})`. You can see that on the doc.

Comment: Yes, had that. I've updated the question with more info

Comment: Same... If I do http://localhost:8101/#/sums-home it works (without go back icon) but it has to be like that, forcing it. If I go from previous page can't see any path changes. I'm doing the push directly to this route and it works, but just the redirection as commented

Comment: You need to set the `defaultHistory: ['list']`.See the doc.

Comment: That adds the back button but again only when I force the url. Why is this routing so complicated? I think this should be quite simple (and important) on every single framework

Comment: This is so simple when we consider the Angular routing system. Just `Push` and `Pop`. I don't know what is going on your app....

Comment: I found a github issue with my problem. Also created and posted a repo with my code: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11517#issuecomment-328933155

Answer (score 1):

I was navigating like `this.nav.setRoot(SumsHomePage);`.

Url seems to change only when navigating using segment: `this.nav.setRoot('sums-home');`